# Incremental BR tag counter isn´t working, something is missing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code, in order to add an incremental counter next to each BR tag, as a per line counter for a lyric song, but it isn´t working. Help is apreciated!

```
<?php $lyrics = "<p>Every time when I look in the mirror <br />All these lines on my face getting clearer <br /> The past is gone <br /> And it went by, like dusk to dawn <br /> Isn't that the way? <br /> Everybody's got their dues in life to pay <br /> Yeah, I know nobody knows <br /> Where it comes and where it goes <br /> I know it's everybody's sin <br /> You got to lose to know how to win <br /></p>";

$arr=explode(PHP_EOL, $lyrics);
foreach($arr as $index=>$ele)
{
echo $ele . $index+1 . "<br />";
} ?>
```

Comment: There aren't any instances of `PHP_EOL` in your string, so it's not splitting anything.

Comment: `PHP_EOL`, `<p>`, `<br>` and `<br />` are all different characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to split the string $lyrics on the PHP_EOL constant (This is a platform dependent constant which refers to the line ending your operating system uses). Instead you should try to split the string by `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way: use "`<br />`" to separate and make each echo single:

```
$lyrics = "<p>Every time when I look in the mirror <br />All these lines on my face getting clearer <br /> The past is gone <br /> And it went by, like dusk to dawn <br /> Isn't that the way? <br /> Everybody's got their dues in life to pay <br /> Yeah, I know nobody knows <br /> Where it comes and where it goes <br /> I know it's everybody's sin <br /> You got to lose to know how to win <br /></p>";

$arr=explode("<br />", $lyrics);
foreach($arr as $index=>$ele)
{
    echo $ele;
    echo $index+1;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That worked BUT I need help to add one variable to the code, and I get it! To also count </p> as well as <br />, OR look and replace </p> for </p><br />, because the latest line doesn´t have a <br /> rather than a </p> as being a paragraph. Sorry for the work and thank you so much!